# django categorizing model instances

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I run:

```
python3 manage.py makemigrations
```

after saving the below code, it shows error:

> todo.Task.status: (fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.

I want to categorize every Task instance according to todo, complete or incomplete. This property is to be specified while creating every Task instance. The tasks are to be shown on different columns on HTML page.

The code below does not work:

```
from django.db import models

STATUS_CHOICES = ('complete', 'incomplete', 'todo')
class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 128)  
    due = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null = True)  
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 16, choices = STATUS_CHOICES)

    def __str__(self):
        return (f"{self.name}")
```

Please Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from django documentation  : Field.choices

An iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting itself of iterables of exactly two items (e.g. [(A, B), (A, B) ...]) to use as choices for this field. If this is given, the default form widget will be a select box with these choices instead of the standard text field.

The first element in each tuple is the actual value to be set on the model, and the second element is the human-readable name. For example:

```
YEAR_IN_SCHOOL_CHOICES = (
    ('FR', 'Freshman'),
    ('SO', 'Sophomore'),
    ('JR', 'Junior'),
    ('SR', 'Senior'),
   )
```

Answer (score 1):

try to assign a value to each choice

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    ('com','complete'),
    ('inc','incomplete'),
    ('to','todo'),
)
```

of course, it's your choice to choose any value that you want